# firebug not running javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

so I typed:

```
alert('wtf');
```

into the firebug console and hit run

However instead of having the browser, alerting 'wtf', the console instead prints

```
>>> alert('wtf');
```

how do I go about making the console actually run javascript instead of just regurgitating my commands..

Comment: Should just work by entering the JavaScript code like you did. Restart Firebug / FireFox?

Comment: restarting didnt work....the thing used to work but suddenly stops

Comment: Maybe there are some other javascript errors earlier in the page that are preventing the console code from working. Try it on a blank html page.

Comment: This may not help for this particular problem, but have a look at http://getfirebug.com/commandline for more information on the console and what you can do with it.

Comment: it doesnt work regardless of what the page is

Comment: Does the console print anything after that? It's supposed to print *`undefined`*.

Comment: no it just regurgitates the command

Comment: Please try with Firebug 1.12, and file an issue if it still reproduces. (1.12 fixed a fair number of issues with command line, like conflicts with content-security-policy.)

Comment: As mentioned @SimonLindholm, Firebug 1.12 has fixed issues related to the command line, like the conflict with content-security-policy (that you would encounter if using the command line when on Github).
If after the upgrade of Firebug, the issue still occurs, could you deactivate the extensions for Firebug (if you have some), restart Firefox and check again?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Restarting firefox solved this problem when I ran into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having the exact same problem. Seems to have started since I upgraded to Firefox 23.0.1. What version are you using? I am thinking about rolling back to the previous version to try and resolve it.

Comment: Having this problem in 25.0.1 as well, thinking it might be something in a version of the plug-in itself.

Comment: @PillarOfLight I am having this same issue.  Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

i had same issue and remove firebug plug-in restart firefox and reinstall firebug solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using FireBug 1.12.x which is compatible with versions FireFox version 23-27.  The FireBug [download page](https://getfirebug.com/downloads/) shows the compatibility of each version of FireBug and FireFox.